# How can I catch any pipeline error in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline script that for the most part works fine and I surround most things that will fire a fatal error with try catches. However from time to time really unexpected things happen and I'd like to be able to have a safe catch-all available to do some final reporting before failing the build.

Is there no final default 'stage' I can define that runs whenever an error isn't caught?

Comment: you can wrap it up in a `try {} finally {}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by wrapping all your build stages in a big `try/catch/finally {}` block, for example:

```
node('yournode') {
    try {
        stage('stage1') {
            // build steps here...
        }
        stage('stage2') {
            // ....
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // error handling, if needed
        // throw the exception to jenkins
        throw e
    } finally {
        // some common final reporting in all cases (success or failure)
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this solution works for declarative approach ?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar for a declarative pipeline, I believe ipper's answer below is the correct solution

Answer (score 14):

Although already been answered for a scripted pipeline I would like to point out that for a **declarative** pipeline this is done with a [post section](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('No-op') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo 'One way or another, I have finished'
            deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
        }
        success {
            echo 'I succeeeded!'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'I am unstable :/'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
        }
        changed {
            echo 'Things were different before...'
        }
    }
}
```

Each stage can also have it's own section when required.

Comment: Is the post stage executed if the timeout occurs ?

Comment: @Siddharth I believe you would see messages from `always` and `failure` in the case of a timeout.